# Tags for relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on an inventory tracking application. Barebones, just for learning. One issue I'm running into is how products can be related. **Categories** works fine, but a **Logitech G35 Mouse** could be nested under **Peripherals**, but **Peripherals** will be populated with mice, keyboards, headphones, Waacom pads, etc. To help find what we need faster I wanted to incorporate *tags* of some sort, but I've noticed there's something called *Tags* native to Django which keeps hijacking my search.

Here's my **Item** model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    introduction = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', default='Uncategorized', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    quanity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_retired = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def add(self):
        pass

    def remove(self):
        pass

    def retire(self): # Rex came up with this, roll credits.
        pass 

    def count(self):
        pass
```

So if I were to add a **Logitech G35 Mouse** as an item, I'd like the tag(s) to be **mouse, mice, wireless** and so forth. Where might I find the information needed to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a model `Tag` and a [many to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) with model `Item`:

```
class Tag(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    introduction = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', default='Uncategorized', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    quanity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_retired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Comment: ```TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use tags.set() instead.```

So I'm confused on this. I've set up tags `mouse` and `mice` and saved them. Now how do I go about applying these tags when instantiating an Item?

Comment: Can you share the code of what you attempted to do?

Comment: ```Item(name='G35', description='Logitech', tags='mice')```

I did soon after realize my error, but I'm still conflicted. If I follow the help text there and use `set()` I'm told that Tag is not iterable, which makers since. If I follow the docs and use `add(tag)` I'm told I'm missing a positional argument so I don't think I'm reaching the method I'm trying to use.

Comment: `mouse = Item(name='G35', description='Logitech')
mouse.save()
mice = Tag.objects.filter(title='mice')
mouse.tags.add(mice)`

This was the solution code for the above. I was using `add()` on the object rather than `tags`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a Many-to-Many relationship. You need a table of products, a table of categories, and a table that shows the relationship between those tables. Here is the sample code from the Django docs. A publication can contain many articles, and an article can be in many publications. To translate this to your models, a product(mouse) can be a part of many categories(mice/mouse/wireless), and a category(wireless) can contain many items(mouse, keyboard, speakers)

```
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/